# Use Cellindex when inserting data in tablelist

Tags: list, tcl

I have a tablelist with 4 rows and 4 columns.
As I understand the documentation I should be able to insert data from a list using the cellindex. When I try this:

```
.dsm.nb.f3.massData insertlist 2 2 [list a b c]
```

I get:

```
wrong # args: should be ".dsm.nb.f3.massData insertlist index itemList"
```

My gues is that I am doing something wrong using the index, but 2 2 (also tried 2,2) looks like a correct index to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insertlist` subcommand inserts **rows** into the tablelist widget. So, the index it requires is a row index, not a cell index. Also, the elements of the itemList are items, not individual cells.

If you want to replace the cell text, you'd want to use `$widget cellconfigure cellindex -text $text` or `$widget rowconfigure rowindex -text $list_of_texts`.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I all the insert commands actually insert new items in the table. But how do I eg write "hello" in the cell in row two in column two? Should be trivial..

Comment: Actually, it's not, I'm afraid. You'll have to delete the row, and insert the new updated one.

Comment: There's a `cellconfigure` subcommand which allows one to change the cell text. I've edited the answer.